# Excel array formula yields FALSE (inconsistent behavior)

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I have a large dataset in Excel (about 80 thousand lines) and I'd like to make a table with the most recent data. The dates are in column A. So I proceed thusly:

```
=INDEX(IF(A:A=MAX(A:A),F:F),1)
```

And the result yielded is FALSE, which is odd enough. Now, if I use the following array formula

```
=SMALL(IF(A:A=MAX(A:A),F:F),1)
```

I get a proper result, but this formula is useless for text data. So why didn't the array formula work in the former case and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why use an array formula?  This is a pretty simple VLOOKUP: `=VLOOKUP(MAX(A:A),A:F,6,FALSE)`

Comment: Of if you'd prefer INDEX/MATCH: `=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(MAX(A:A),A:A,0))`

Comment: There is more than one entry per date, unfortunately.

Comment: so column A is the date?  Is there a reason you don't just sort by column A with newest on top? or filter for the most recent date?

Comment: The reason you get `FALSE` is that INDEX unlike SMALL does not care if it is a number, text, or Boolean.  The Array `IF(A:A=MAX(A:A),F:F)` returns values in F where TRUE and `FALSE` where FALSE. So the `1` in the INDEX formula will return the first item in the list whether it be the first value in F if A is the max date or `FALSE` if it is not.  The SMALL is designed to ignore text and Boolean values and only look at numeric values, thus it returns the lowest number.  With 80,000 lines vba or sorting will be your answer.  Array formulas will take too much comp power and may crash Excel.